# Get main color in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am use react-native to build my app and now i am facing an problem with an UI module which need me to get main color of an image programmatically as the background of UI. How can i make it with react-native way?

Comment: ps: the image is remote url with http  not local assets

Answer (score 3):

You can try [react-native-color-grabber](https://github.com/bsudekum/react-native-color-grabber) . Given an image, returns dominant colors.

```
var colorGrabber = require('react-native').NativeModules.colorGrabber
colorGrabber.getColors(image, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res);
    // Returns:
    // {
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0784314 0.0941176 0.0823529 1': '0.1666667',
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.215686 0.203922 0.262745 1': '0.1666667',
    //  'UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.517647 0.45098 0.380392 1': '0.6666667'
    // }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not specific in getting the exact colors of the image and are only looking to present the image in a nice background with the same color scheme as the image (while keeping the image's aspect ratio) you can work around this by using a blur effect and doubling the image in the back of the blur as so ->

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

/* components */
import {BlurView} from '@react-native-community/blur';

/* styles */
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window')
const DESIRED_HEIGHT = 200;

....

render() {
  var {source} = this.props;

  return (
    <>
      <ImageBackground style={[styles.containerStyle, styles.blur]} source={source}>
        <BlurView
          style={styles.containerStyle}
          blurType="light"
          blurAmount={10}
          reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
        />
      </ImageBackground>
      <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={source} />
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    height: DESIRED_HEIGHT,
    width,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: DESIRED_HEIGHT,
    width,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  blur: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

What will happen is that the image will contain itself and keep its aspect ratio while the background image will cover the whole area and the blur will give you the desired effect of the image's color scheme.

This is the default behavior in the iOS Gallery app.

Comment: I would like to mention only that source variable in your great example should be in form of an object what means source: { uri: string } regarding to docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground)

Answer (score -1):

Use can use this wonderful library
[react-palette](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-palette)

```
import { usePalette } from 'react-palette'

const { data, loading, error } = usePalette(IMAGE_URL)

<View style={{ backgroundColor: data.vibrant }}>
  Text with the vibrant color
</View>
```

Sample output of data variable

```
{
  darkMuted: "#2a324b"
  darkVibrant: "#0e7a4b"
  lightMuted: "#9cceb7"
  lightVibrant: "#a4d4bc"
  muted: "#64aa8a"
  vibrant: "#b4d43c"
}
```

Comment: it seems required node env

Comment: @HugeBelieve Does this work with React Native or just React?

Comment: Hi in the usePalette(IMAGE_URL), what do we set for IMAGE_URL if we want to use image from assets?
I used both require("../assets/image.png")
and "../assets/image.png" both returned empty data object

Comment: This is for React, and not React Native